# Optimize a mysql statement has been executed for more than 42000 ms

Tags: mysql

I use Mysql 8, InnoDB engine.

I have 7000+ data in `p_summary` table, 11000+ data in `p_ranking` table.

To select top 30 player(not be deleted) id accroding to their sum of atk and def, I used the following sql:

```
select p_ranking.id, p_ranking.atk+p_ranking.def s from p_ranking where ifnull((select p_summary.deleted from p_summary where p_summary.id = p_ranking.id), 1) = 0 order by s desc limit 0,30
```

The execution of this sql statement took `42000` ms, which is extremely slow. What aspects can I approach to improve? For example, modifying sql statements, creating indexes, and so on

The execution plan with only one result:

```
| id   | select_type        | table     | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref               | rows | filtered | Extra                       |
| ---- | ------------------ | --------- | ---------- | ------ | ------------- | ------- | ------- | ----------------- | ---- | -------- | --------------------------- |
| 1    | PRIMARY            | p_ranking |            | ALL    |               |         |         |                   | 1    | 100.00   | Using where; Using filesort |
| 2    | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | p_summary |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | game.p_ranking.id | 1    | 100.00   |                             |
```

Comment: What does the execution plan tell you about this?

Comment: Please share all details **in text form**, not embedded into a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p_ranking.id, (p_ranking.atk + p_ranking.def) AS s
FROM p_ranking
JOIN p_summary ON p_summary.id = p_ranking.id
WHERE p_summary.deleted = 0
ORDER BY s DESC
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Comment: Efficiency has doubled